# Changing the index of a summation - what is it called?

Tags: sequences-and-series, reference-request, terminology

About $\sum$ (summation), what is it called when you change the index of a summation? My teacher does it all the time and I just don't get it! Please send some links so I can learn it.

Answer (score 1):

It's basically called what you called it, usually something like "*re-indexing a summation*" or "*changing the indexing of a summation*" or "*shifting the indexing of a summation*".

Comment: Oooh thanks! i will look it up, Sometimes

Answer (score 1):

There appears to not be a specific name for this process, as Zev Chonoles indicates, just to add to the explanation, according to ["Summation Notation"](http://www.columbia.edu/itc/sipa/math/summation.html), you would probably need to state whether or not you are changing the *upper limit* or *lower limit* of the summation.

In terms of your request for links, here are some that may be of help:

["Summation Notation and Series"](http://math.uchicago.edu/~vipul/teaching-0910/153/seriesofreals.pdf) University of Chicago

["Changing Summation Limits"](http://blogs.ubc.ca/infiniteseriesmodule/units/unit-1/sigma-notation/changing-summation-limits/) University of British Columbia (wiki)

["Summation Notation"](http://pine.cs.yale.edu/pinewiki/SummationNotation) Yale (wiki)

Hope these help.